# Checking stdin and stdout using external function

Tags: c, stdout, stdin, ferror

Does scope impact, checking for errors while obtaining input from stdin or outputting to stdout? For example if I have a code body built in the following way:

```
void streamCheck(){
   if (ferror(stdin)){
      fprintf(stderr, "stdin err");
      exit(1);
   }
   if (ferror(stdout)){
      fprintf(stderr, "stdout err");
      exit(2);
   }
}

int main(){
   int c = getchar();
   streamCheck();
   ...
   putchar(c) 
   streamCheck();
}
```

are the return values of ferror(stdin) / ferror(stdout) impacted by the fact that I am checking them in a function rather than in the main? If there is a better way to do this also let me know I am quite new to C.

Comment: `main()` is a function, too.

Answer (score 2):

As long as you call `ferror` on a particular stream before calling any other function on that stream you should be fine.

It doesn't matter that `ferror` is being called from a different function that `getchar` or `putchar` was called from.

Comment: Why the "before calling any other function" concern? `ferror()` results reflect history.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica If for example you make two function calls that handle `stdout` before calling `ferror` you don't know which call triggered the error.

Answer (score 1):

There is no problem in your function. `ferror()` checks the error indicator of the `FILE *` that is passed as argument. In other words, the error indicator is a property of the file object and is directly obtainable from the `FILE *` pointer. Therefore, no matter where you call `ferror()` from, it will be able to determine if an error happened with the `FILE *` that is passed as argument (that is, of course, if the argument is valid).

Answer (score 0):

> are the return values of ferror(stdin) / ferror(stdout) impacted by
>   the fact that I am checking them in a function rather than in the
>   main?

The return value of `ferror()` is characteristic of the current state of the stream that you provide as an argument.  At any given time, the `stdin` provided by `stdio.h` refers to the same stream, with the same state, in every function, including `main()`.  Therefore, you will obtain the same result by calling the `ferror()` function indirectly, via an intermediary function, as you would by calling it directly.

NEVERTHELESS, the approach you present in your example is poor.  For the most part, C standard library functions indicate whether an error has occurred via their return values.  In particular, `getchar()` returns a special value, represented by the macro `EOF`, if *either* the end of the file is encountered or an error occurs.  This is typical of the stdio functions.  You should consistently test functions' return values  to recognize when exceptional conditions have occurred.  For stream functions, you should call `ferror()` and / or `feof()` only after detecting such a condition, and only if you want to distinguish between the end-of-file case and the I/O error case (and the "neither" case for some functions).  See also ["Why is 'while ( !feof (file) )' always wrong?"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5431941/2402272)

Personally, I probably would not write a generic function such as your `streamCheck()` at all, as error handling is generally situation specific.  But if I did write one, then I'd certainly have it test just one stream that I specify to it.  Something like this, for example:

```
void streamCheck(FILE *stream, const char *message, int exit_code) {
   if (ferror(stream)) {
      fputs(message, stderr);
      exit(exit_code);
   }
}

int main(void) {
   int c = getchar();

   if (c == EOF) {
       streamCheck(stdin, "stdin err\n", 1);
   }

   // ...

   if (putchar(c) == EOF) {
       streamCheck("stdout err\n", 2);
   }
}
```

Comment: correct me if I'm wrong but ```getchar()``` returns ```EOF``` for when the end of file is reached OR when an error occurs, but ```ferror(FILE* stream)``` only returns true if an error has occurred but not when end of file has been reached. So you can make less function calls since you are only checking for errors when ```EOF``` is returned?

Comment: @nutella100, yes, this answer explicitly observes that `getchar()` and most other stdio functions return EOF both on reaching the end of the file and on encountering an I/O error.  You do make *many* fewer calls to `ferror()` if you only call it when an I/O function has returned `EOF`, and that's worthwhile.  But I fear that you are missing a key point: as a much more general rule, **you need to check the return values of your function calls** and respond appropriately.  The specific handling discussed here is a particular case of a broader principle.